# Rails Json response help

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json

In my controller i have:

```
@photo = Photo.find(:all)

respond_to do |format|
...
format.json { render :json => @photo.to_json)

end
```

so my response looks like:

```
{
        "photo":
        {
            "updated_at":"2010-10-14T19:12:35Z",
            "photo_file_size":206422,
            "created_at":"2010-10-14T19:12:01Z"
        }
    },
    {
        "photo":
        {
            "updated_at":"2010-10-16T18:19:38Z",
            "photo_file_size":83593,
            "created_at":"2010-10-14T19:14:35Z"
        }
    }
```

how can i add an additional json key value pair for every photo block?
something like:

```
"photo":
        {
            "updated_at":"2010-10-14T19:12:35Z",
            "photo_file_size":206422,
            "created_at":"2010-10-14T19:12:01Z"
 ---->      "created_at_b":"2010/10/14"
        }
```

maybe `:include` option?

thanks!

Answer (score 2):

to_json can be made to include the result of any method available on your model.  For example you could add the following method to your model:

```
class Photo < ActiveRecord::Base
  def created_at_b
    # whatever you want to do
  end
end
```

In your controller you add:

```
format.json { render :json => @photo.to_json(:methods=>[:created_at_b])
```

That should return the json that you're after.

Comment: How can i add in every photo the "created_at_b" field?

Comment: That's what the first block of code is for,  you'd put that method definition in your model class.  I've edited the answer so it's a bit more clear